# Where node.js was installed?

Tags: arch-linux, node.js

I have installed node.js by :

```
$ yaourt -S nodejs
```

But where node.js (Dir) was installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the file list on the arch packages list (click on `View the file list for nodejs` on [the packages page](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/nodejs/) or use `pacman --query --list nodejs` to view the content of the installed nodejs package.

Answer (score 1):

Use which to find the path:
$ which node

> WHICH(1)
>
> NAME
>          which - locate a command
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          which [-a] filename ...
>   
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

### using Linux `which` command find Node.js installed path

```bsh
$ which node
/Users/xgqfrms-mbp/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/bin/node

$ which npm 
/Users/xgqfrms-mbp/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/bin/npm
```

```bsh
$ echo $PATH
# get all env paths
```